# React Bootstrap error: 'AccordionCollapseProps' is not exported from './AccordionCollapse'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I added Bootstrap and routing to a frontend, deleted my node_modules, and re-installed them with yarn install. When I try to `npm run build`, I get:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js
Attempted import error: 'AccordionCollapseProps' is not exported from './AccordionCollapse'.
```

I'd like to fix this error. I can post more extensive code if helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an open issue in their github repo:
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5267

One reported fix is to roll back to version **1.0.1**.

> npm install react-bootstrap@1.0.1 --save

That worked for me.

Comment: nice this just fixed my issue too. I'm guessing another version came out between 2 days ago and today

Answer (score 5):

After zxvaf's solution if the problem still continues you should also remove ^ character from react-bootstrap in package.json file.
So it should be like this

```
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers using `create-react-app` with Typescript template, **updating Typescript version to 3.8** did the trick for me.

```
npm install typescript@3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleted `node_modules` and `npm i` again, that **worked for me**. Might also be some cache problem never forget that.